# how to let my jcenter library always use the latest android-support version?

Tags: android, android-support-library

In my libray project, it use the `android-support` library, if i uploaded to the jcenter, it will not can change the dependency version, how can i always use the latest version of `android-support` use this library?
[image]

Comment: Since the Support Library frequently makes far reaching and breaking changes, depending always on the latest is a recipe for disaster. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: you could use:
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
but as @ianhanniballake it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @ianhanniballake if do not will come multi version in project whick use this library.

Comment: That's not how Gradle resolves dependencies. What problem are you actually experiencing?

Comment: @ianhanniballake in my library use android-support 24.0.0, in a project use android-support 25.0.0, if this project use this library will come two different verson of android-support, how to resolve it

Comment: Have you tried it? Explain exactly what problem you are experiencing, not what problem you think exists.

Comment: Yeah, actually come two different version. one is from library, the other is from the project.

Comment: " in a project use android-support 25.0.0, if this project use this library will come two different verson of android-support" -- as Ian indicates, that is not how Gradle works. Gradle has automatic version conflict resolution, and there are resolution strategies that you can configure. Moreover, your proposed solution would make the problem worse. If you feel that you have found a bug in Gradle's conflict resolution, create a **complete** project that reproduces the issue, and either file a bug report, or link to the project from here, so that others can look at it.

Comment: I think that's my problem, if u do not write death, the library always use the latest version of android-support, unless, u depend a older android-support version, it will come two different version, just change ur project dependency to the latest.